# ESlint rule for specific folders naming conventions

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a mono repo with a lot of projects, and we have one linter project for all the other projects.

I'm trying to make all the folder names (Inside src folder) to be kebab-case, expect for the following:

```
__test__
__tests__
__mock__
__mocks__
```

This is what I have so far:

```
  'check-file/folder-naming-convention': [
    'error',
    {
      'src/!(__test__|__tests__|__mock__|__mocks__)**/': 'KEBAB_CASE',
    },
  ],
```

But for some reason I still get lint error:

```
The folder "__tests__" does not match the "KEBAB_CASE" pattern
```

for path like: `project/project/__test__/my-test.ts`

Any ides?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/DukeLuo/eslint-plugin-check-file/blob/main/docs/rules/folder-naming-convention.md#custom-patterns) it recommends `src/!(__tests__)/**/` for this, but you don't the same `/` before the `**`. If you add that, does that fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: `src/!(__tests__)/**/` doesn't work because the `**` pattern will match anything, including `_tests`. Try `src/!(__tests__)/?([A-Z]*)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one solve the issue for me:

```
'src/**/!(_test|tests|mock|mocks_)/': 'KEBAB_CASE',
```